# No coercion operator error with Linq query with Select new

Tags: linq, sqlite

I'm using UWP, Sqlite and Linq to make ObservableCollections to bind to my XAML Listviews. No problems thus far.
Next I like to have the results of a join query into a List, also to bind to a Listview.
This results in an error even with the simplified code below:

```
    public class BooksAndSeries
    {
        public int PublYear { get; set; }
        public string SeriesName { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
    public static List<BooksAndSeries> SelBooksSeries { get; set; }
    public static void LoadSearchedBooks()
    {
        using (CatDataContext catDB = new myBooks.Model.CatDataContext())
        {
            var SearchedBooks = from Book bb in catDB.Books
                                select new BooksAndSeries { PublYear = bb.PublYear, Title = bb.Title };
            SelBooksSeries = new List<BooksAndSeries>(SearchedBooks);
        }
    }
```

The query gives the error:
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=No coercion operator is defined between types 'myBooks.GenModule+BooksAndSeries' and 'myBooks.Model.Book'.
  Source=
  StackTrace:

I'm using the latest Microsoft VS Community edition and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite 1.1.5.

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. I think `SearchedBooks.ToList()` would be more idiomatic. What type does the editor think is in `SearchedBooks`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Changing into SearchedBooks.ToList() doesn't change things. The type of SearchedBooks is {Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable<TestSplitView.GenModule.BooksAndSeries>}. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Is a newer version of EF Core available? I'm thinking it might be something I've seen as fixed in later versions???

Comment: I think you remembered very well. After updating Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore  and .Sqlite 1.1.5 with version 2.0.2 the error I mentione was gone. Thanks again for your comments.